How do I power two 3W blubs from a power bank?
A friend of mine has a cupboard that includes two 3W light bulbs (the kind that are meant to look like flickering flames in case it makes any difference). There is a wire out of the back of the cupboard, with a standard (UK) 2-pin plug that goes into a wall socket and powers the bulbs. The bulbs are usually only on for a couple of hours each day.
However, he just moved the cupboard, and it's now no longer near a socket. It's not practical to install a socket in the new location, and he can't use an extension wire as it would be a tripping hazard.
He wondered about getting some sort of power bank to power the bulbs. Given the low wattage and low usage of the bulbs, the assumption was that a power bank would only need charging once in a while, at which point it could be taken out of the cupboard and recharged near a socket.
He tried a couple of power banks (didn't manage to find out exactly which ones, but I can try again if it helps), but neither of them worked. The lights just didn't come on.
Update I have since confirmed that most (all?) UPSs will go inactive if no power is being drawn. Given the low wattage of these bulbs, it seems that the UPSs he tried didn't register that anything was plugged in.
Anyone any advice as to how he can manage this? Is there a UPS that will work with such low wattage, or are there any other ways of doing this?
Thanks for any advice you can give.

Perhaps the power bank wasn't the right voltage. Sounds like it was originally supplied by the mains voltage (230 volts) with alternating current.

@WeatherVane As I said, I'm not sure exactly what he tried, but as far as I know, it was the same sort of thing you use as a back for (say) a PC (like this one for example... https://www.amazon.co.uk/gp/product/B0B3RQN8QT/?th=1), which is supposed to supply the same as the mains, but that keeps power if the mains fails

Do the lights still work when an extension is used to a mains socket?

@WeatherVane Yes


He wondered about getting some sort of power bank to power the bulbs. Given the low wattage and low usage of the bulbs, the assumption was that a power bank would only need charging once in a while, at which point it could be taken out of the cupboard and recharged near a socket.

Sorry, ain't gonna happen, except if you pay a huge amount of money and are willing to tolerate an extremely heavy power bank with ridiculously low runtime.
The power bank you need for this use case is one with an inverter.
The problem is, the cheapest power banks from China from companies like Ecoflow or Bluetti include true sine wave inverters that consume a lot of power even at idle.
My Ecoflow River Mini Wireless (210 watt-hours, weight 2.85 kg) at 95% charge (to prolong its lifetime as lithium ion doesn't like full charge) has a runtime of 17 hours when no AC load is connected. Thus, the idle power usage is 11.7 watts. The cost of this power bank is about 300 EUR.
If we assume that the 6 watts of light bulbs total are powered with an efficiency of 90%, then the total consumption is 11.7 W + 6 W / 0.9 = 18.4 watts.
18.4 watts just to power 6 watts is insanely wasteful. At 18.4 watts, the runtime is 11.4 hours and you need to explicitly remember to turn on and off the power bank since if the power bank is on but the lights are off, power is still wasted.
There is a technology that might allow very good efficiency for low loads of about ten watts or less. It's an extremely well designed modified square wave inverter. It can't be the ordinary Chinese square wave inverters that run at constant duty cycle, but it rather has to be a unit that lowers the duty cycle or even turns the power transformer off until the voltage has sagged a bit, after which point the power transformer is quickly used again to bring up the output voltage.
Not all loads like modified square wave. For example, several cheap circuits that use a capacitor as a current limiter don't work with square wave at all. I'm not sure if the 6 watt bulbs will be destroyed by modified square wave, the only way to find out would be to try. They won't be destroyed by sine wave but as I said, sine wave inverters are extremely inefficient for low loads.
However, you won't find an efficient modified square wave inverter anywhere. The ones that are well-designed are sine wave, and the ones that are cheap are built as cheaply as possible so they don't use the opportunity to make the unit extremely efficient at low loads, but rather they minimize the component count to make things cheap.
The best bet would be to replace the light bulbs by 12V / 24V bulbs if you can find those, and then use a step-up or step-down converter to modify the voltage from a raw battery (such as LiFePO4 or something like a Ryobi 18V tool battery) into 12V or 24V and then power the bulbs via DC. The bulbs most likely run on DC anyway, the AC is just an intermediate stage that makes things very inefficient if you have a DC power source.
The biggest Ryobi tool battery is 9 Ah, 18 V so it's 162 Wh. At efficiency of 95% (typical of the cheap Chinese DC-DC converters you can find on AliExpress), it runs the 6 watt load for 25.7 hours. The cheap Chinese DC-DC converters can be found with idle current of as little as 5 mA, so if you don't power the lights on at all, the battery would still last for 75 days without a separate power switch for the DC-DC converter! Also, if the bulbs are dual 12V/24V, they most likely can run on a 18V tool battery already with no DC-DC converter inbetween.
If 25.7 hours on / 75 days off isn't enough runtime, then I'm sure you will find even bigger LiFePO4 batteries that actually may already have a compatible voltage so a DC-DC converter is not needed.
Whatever you do, don't plan on using a cheap USB power bank. They have at most 2-3 A of current at 5 V, so 10 - 15 W. This could barely power bulbs of 6 watts total, with a step-up converter, if the bulbs were DC bulbs. However, with AC bulbs no way is this going to run an inverter. A raw battery where you can access the output terminals yourself is a better choice.

Besides, there is a clean solution. There are small cable ducts with adhesive backing intended for a single extension cord. Buy a 10 meter extension cord, then route it as you want with the small cable ducts, and you have a clean solution with electricity where you need. I recently used this solution to bring continuous power to a Raspberry Pi that's in an unusual location.

Wow, what a fantastic answer! Not what I was hoping to hear, but very detailed and clear. Thanks very much. Unfortunately, due to the new position of the cupboard, cable ducts are not an option, as there is a high-traffic zone on either side, and the risk of tripping is too great. I guess he'll have to look at some sort of battery-power lights. Thanks again.

@AvrohomYisroel I hope you realize that because these cable ducts have adhesive backing, you can route them on walls and on the ceiling. So if the cupboard is near a wall and the room where it's in has at least one socket somewhere, you can route cables tidily, since your sockets are installed in walls too. You don't have to route them on the floor.

Thanks, I did realise that, but this cupboard is by a partition wall that is sometimes moved, so he can't use the walls. Thanks anyway, he's investigating having a channel dug into the concrete floor. Messy, but would solve all the problems. Thanks again
